# Loading doc and docx files into python

Tags: python, ms-word

I am trying to load a ton of files half of which are .docx the current word file extension and half are .doc the circa 2007 word file extension. I am using the python docx module to open them grab certain values and store them in arrays. My problem is that the docx module is not capable of loading .doc files.

I tried using this code to upload the files and then change the extension name to .docx.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('mypath') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('mypath', f))]
for f in range(0, len(files)):
    files[f] = os.path.splitext(files[f])[0] + '.docx'
```

But I encounter this error when I try to load a document the was previously .doc

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'mypath\\doc.docx'
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can load a .doc file besides going into each file and doing a save as .docx in microsoft word. This is not feasible as there are a lot of documents.

Thanks

Comment: `.docx` is a type of XML file and Microsoft has made the file specification open, but the old `.doc` files use proprietary Microsoft formats. There _are_ some non-Microsoft converters available for such files but they may not work on all files. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_%28computing%29#Specification) for some details.

Comment: Google "doc to docx batch converter"